# Extract properties of sql connection string

Tags: c#, substring

I want to extract from a connectionString (a string variable) the server and database names. The name of the server and database change as we move from DEV to STAGE and then PROD.

Here's an example:

```
Data Source=SERVER_XYZ;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_XYZ;User ID=us;Password=pass

Data Source=SERVER_XYZPQR;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_XYZPQR;User ID=us;Password=pass
```

Notice the name changes (as well as lengths of the whole string).

How do I capture the data source and initial catalog without knowing the length it's going to be? So that on form load, it'll get the Server & Database name to display to the user (so he/she can see which server and database he/she is connected to?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: @Daniel not when .net provides a class to handle this

Comment: @Daniel: *you have a problem and decide to solve it using a regex. Now you have two ...*

Comment: IMHO regex's are a great addition to a developers toolbox, just that I don't think it should be used as a hammer...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the connection string builder class which once constructed has datasource and initial catalog properties

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx

```
string connStr = "Data Source=SERVERx;Initial Catalog=DBx;User ID=u;Password=p"; 

var csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connStr);

string dataSource = csb.DataSource;
string initialCatalog = csb.InitialCatalog;
```

Let the .net framework do the work for you ;) no messing about with substrings or regexs

Comment: ah thanks! a different way of doing it.

Comment: +1 I like this better than the accepted answer because it's less prone to bugs IMAO.

Comment: @user1336632 you shouldn't think of this as an *alternative* solution; this is the correct solution! When the .net framework provides a class to handle your scenario, you really should be using it.

Comment: thanks all. i'm using this now. :)

Comment: +1 : Regex is fun, but this makes far much more sense than my answer. I didn't even know the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class existed! Using as a boiler plate now for building my connection strings now.

Comment: Very clean and elegant solution! nice! I did the same with 
OracleConnectionStringBuilder - worked like a charm , saved me a lot of headache

Answer (score 5):

A C# Regex solution:

```
String input = "Data Source=SERVER_XYZ;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_XYZ;User ID=us;Password=pass";

// Match the server:
Match serverMatch = Regex.Match(input, @"Source=([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Match the database:
Match databaseMatch = Regex.Match(input, @"Catalog=([A-Za-z0-9_]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Get the string
if (serverMatch.Success)
{
  String server = serverMatch.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Keep in mind valid characters for URLs:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=
```

Comment: and then to display it simply do this? lblServer.Text = serverMatch.ToString(); lblDatabase.Text = databaseMatch.ToString();

Comment: that worked. what if I don't want to display the "Source=" and "Catalog=" ?

Comment: that worked. thanks! :) ps. regex and Linq have some real ugly syntaxes!